# Sails.js Can't create data in another model from other model's lifecycle

Tags: mysql, sails.js

Hey I'm kinda new to Sails. I've enabled REST api in sails and no I just simply create data using the body of the post request body without the intervention of a controller.
I have defined two models - users, and call_log. Every time an event occurs in my app, I want that to trigger a change in the value of a user in the users table but I also want to create a log in the call log table.
I'm using an `afterCreate()` lifecycle method and try to use the `create()` in order to write my data to the second table. I don't seem to get any error, but nothing is written to the dB.

my User.js (model)

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    username: {type: 'string', required: true},
    country: {type: 'string'},

  },

  afterCreate: function (valuesToSet, proceed) {
    Talk_log.create({
      uid: 'myuid',
      partner_uid: 'mypartnerid',
      action: 'yeahhh'
    }).fetch();
    valuesToSet.password = 1244;
    return proceed();
  },


};
```

my Talk_log.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    uid: { type: 'string', required: true},
    partner_uid: {type: 'string'},
    action: {type: 'string'}

  },

};
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks) say "The afterCreate lifecycle callback will only be run on queries that have the fetch meta flag set to true"

So use:

```
User.create().fetch();
```

Fetch tell Waterline (and the underlying database adapter) to send back records that were updated/destroyed/created when performing an .update(), .create(), .createEach() or .destroy() query.

U say afterCreate() but in your code is beforeCreate(). Fix that.

Comment: I've edited the change you've suggested, but it doesn't work still.

Comment: What sails version u use? Did u use fetch on User.create ? Can u show code from controller?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the `.then()` that handles the bluebird promises and only then I could write to dB.

```
Talk_log.update({ uid: valuesToSet.uid})
  .set({ joined: true})
    .fetch()
      .then(() => {return proceed();});
```